# JAVA invalid maximum heap size. The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size

Tags: java

I have to run this command to fix the code to a xml file:

```
java -Xmx5G -cp .:jsoup-1.8.2.jar CheckSyntax test.xml > test2.xml
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx5G
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Maybe because Java uses 32-bit pointers on your machine?

Comment: You are using the 32-bit version of Java. To allow more than ~2GB of maximum heap size, you need to use the 64-bit version.

Comment: Have you tried `-d64`?

Comment: strange thing: java -64 'this java instance does not support a 64-bit JVM'

Comment: that means you are not using a 64 bit version.  Check `java -version`

Answer (score 16):

If your JVM is 32-bit you cannot use the switch -d64

Answer (score 8):

```
java -Xmx2G -cp .:jsoup-1.8.2.jar CheckSyntax test.xml > test2.xml
```

32 bit java cant use heapsize > 2G

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link to get Java 64bit to allow a larger heap-size. Just select the "Windows Offline (64-bit)" option.
https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: It might be a good idea to add a quick summary of other answers to explain why the poster would benefit from a 64bit version of Java, so any other people looking at this question in the future gets a complete idea of how to solve their problem by looking at your answer.