# Invalid initial heap size -Xms4096M

Tags: java, cassandra, development-environment

I'm trying to run Cassandra on my computer, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms4096M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Anyone know why and how to fix this?

I am running:

```
Windows 10 Pro 64bit
Java 32 Bit
```

It seems I need to install a 64bit version of JRE.  I have tried searching java.com and oracle.com for this, but I can't find anything obvious which will let me install a 64bit JRE.  The default installer from java.com seems to be 32bit.  Can someone please let me know how and where to get the 64bit JRE from?

Comment: This is a duplicate question (and not a Cassandra problem), e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172510/java-invalid-maximum-heap-size-the-specified-size-exceeds-the-maximum-represent

Answer (score 2):

Since the JVM needs more space than just the heap like swap space and VM overhead, the maximum heapspace in a 32Bit JVM should be lower than 4GB.

- You can try out setting the maximum heapspace to 2GB with:
  `-Xmx2048M`
- Alternatively you can just install a 64Bit JVM.

For more information, check out the [Oracle FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit) for the HotSpot JVM

Answer (score 0):

> Java 32 Bit

While the theoretical maximum heap size is indeed 4G for 32 bit, the actual max size is lower than this, as described [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434901/8204697). Use 64 Bit JRE to avoid this.

Comment: I've been trying to install JRE 64Bit, but can't find it.  I go to the Java website and it does not give me a 64 bit option.  After installing it using the default installer, it seems to install a 32bit version.