# How to fix ERROR: No signature of method: build_ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma.android()?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

ERROR: No signature of method: build_ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma$_run_closure1) values: [build_ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma$_run_closure1@47588b04]

The build gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android{
    implementationSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.uiresource.taksiku"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3-alpha', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$var"
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        testimplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta5'
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
        }
```

Comment: check my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66292426/how-do-you-fix-the-following-error-a-problem-occurred-evaluating-project-app/74282362#74282362

Answer (score 144):

If you are using kotlin version 1.4.21 or newer, kotlin-android-extension is deprecated.
So if you removing the plugin you also have to remove the android experimental extension block.
In my case, I had to remove these pieces of code.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

### But if above did not fix it

This a kind of general and/or **wrapping** error which hides the real cause and/or problem, hence to see actual error message, try something like:

```
./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

> And search for resulting real error-message instead.

Comment: Thanks for this! Seems like that snippet should be added to the migration [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) AS points you to for the deprecation notice.

Comment: Thanks. Imagine, this is what AS gave me: `> No signature of method: build_1vktrv59g77woj77yc4fmjh74.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1vktrv59g77woj77yc4fmjh74$_run_closure1) values: [build_1vktrv59g77woj77yc4fmjh74$_run_closure1@3918b394]`

Comment: the `./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace` indeed helps to identify what the problem is .

Answer (score 46):

I had the same error message until I commented out everything in the android plugin except the compile sdk version, trying to get back to a successful build config.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
/*
    ...
*/
}
```

Then, I started uncommenting things until I narrowed the problem down to using the following incorrectly.

```
ProductFlavors {
  ...
}
```

I'm not sure if you're using the same block, but at the moment, I'm leaving it commented out because I'm not sure it's needed. Once I got rid of it though, I was receiving other errors about sdk root dir location, so I was able to fix those.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Was ```kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'```
    } for me

Comment: @ShHolmes me too

Comment: I have the same problem with the `release` block within the `signingConfigs` block, my configuration looks correct, this is messed up, I don't know how I can fix it, commenting is no solution.

Comment: Good trick for debuging..

Comment: `until I commented out everything in the android plugin` worked for me.

Comment: in my case, commenting this line worked in android { } - //    lint {
//        abortOnError false
//        xmlReport true
//    }
//    namespace 'co.abc.client'

Comment: I had this issue, it was because I had a `-` in the product flavor name, which isn't allowed. I switched to camelCase.

Answer (score 43):

I was getting a similar error because the `versionCode` was being taken from a properties file, but the versionCode needs to be an integer and not a string, so `toInteger()` was needed.

Nice logs, android.

Comment: this also happened to me, checking version code solved the issue

Comment: this was a lot helpful!! my case was about versionCode number, which i set by using System.getenv("NEW_BUILD_NUMBER"), thats is a string! and i had to use System.getenv("NEW_BUILD_NUMBER").toInteger()

Comment: Well those logs are from Gradle, not Android. Most Gradle errors are very confusing, because groovy is doing a lot of magic in the background.

Comment: I've been bashing my head against the wall for hours because of this. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I had the version code be the same as the Date.now() timestamp. Probably this integer is to big or something, because changing it to 130 worked.

Comment: @JaapWeijland probably because Date.now() returns a Long, and it cannot be casted automatically to Int.

Comment: checking version code solved my issue, thank you

Answer (score 26):

This is a syntax error somewhere in your gradle file inside the android {} closure. If you are someone having this same problem then the best solution to this problem is to comment out portions of code inside android {} and keep running gradle sync until you have a successful build. Then slowly add back commented out lines until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 18):

Best thing you can do is comment parts of your `build.gradle` file related to the issue until you get a good build and them uncomment 1 by 1 until you find the problem. I had the same error and it was related with a typo in one of the app `build.gradle` blocks. I was using:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeature {
        ...
    }
}
```

instead of

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        ...
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Look at your answer example, it's totally wrong..you had report the same lines..

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano In my answer the difference is between `buildFeature` vs `buildFeatures` with an `s` at the end. the later is the correct one.

Answer (score 18):

in my case I needed to comment out this lines in gradle

```
androidExtensions{
    experimental = true
}
```

Answer (score 17):

This issue is usually related to some change on build.gradle file, for example in my case, was this line in the defaultConfig section on that file:

```
versionCode 1.1
```

I changed it to:

```
versionCode 2
```

and problem fixed.

Comment: Isso, foi isso!

Answer (score 14):

I removed this code from my Gradle:

```
javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

In **Android Studio 2021.1.1 Canary 12**, I removed

```
plugins{
   ...
   id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

But forgot to remove this from

```
android{
    androidExtensions {
            experimental = true
        }
}
```

after removing androidExtension block my problem solved

Answer (score 11):

There's no unique solution for this error, except that it's a syntax error inside `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 10):

I was checking a very old project from Github and found the solution by matching the app level `build.gradle` file with my current project, hence the solution is to replace

```
runProguard false
```

with

```
minifyEnabled false
```

It must've been deprecated and removed in a later build which caused a similar issue - `No signature of method: build_6f958jjxpxn7lllu9wu5brezx.android()`

Answer (score 10):

I just removed `useProguard true` in build.gradle > android > buildTypes, and it worked for me.

Comment: I tried almost all the above and below options......And I just removed useProguard true from my Gradle file and its working now

Answer (score 8):

I'm using JAVA, but for some reason Android Studio added `kotlinOptions` into `android` block without my knowledge. And then the same error happened. I put here just in case someone need it.

```
android {
    // ...

    // remove this block if you are using Java
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to Android but i got a message similar to yours today when i try to use a different version (not the suggested ones) of the Gradle plugin and gradle engine on Android Studio 4.1 canary.

When I had on my App build.gradle these lines:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper){
    gradleVersion = '5.6.4'
}
```

and on my build.gradle for the module this line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
```

This was the message i got with previous settings:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_5dcjpn4h9nkpym0yszxs5w2uh.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_5dcjpn4h9nkpym0yszxs5w2uh$_run_closure1) values: [build_5dcjpn4h9nkpym0yszxs5w2uh$_run_closure1@2e4515b3]
```

The way i found to solve this error was changing version for the gradle plugin on my build.gradle for the module like this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

I hope this could help you. 
Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

It is because there's syntax error in `android{..}` part of build.gradle
You've used `implementationSdkVersion` which should ideally be `compileSdkVersion`. Error in variable names in `android{..}` leads to such errors.

**TLDR;**

Replace `implementationSdkVersion` with `compileSdkVersion`

Answer (score 4):

i was trying to add parcelable plugin in my project. this was the same error in my case too. Because,  JetBrains extracted the **Parcelize** from Kotlin Android Extensions to a new plugin, **kotlin-parcelize**

So, If you want to add easy parcelable in kotlin then follow these steps:

First you will need to add kotlin-parcelize plugin to your module

```
plugins {
    ..
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

Then change your old import statement from

```
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

to

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```

**Example:**

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

import android.os.Parcelable

@Parcelize
class User(

val name: String, 
val age: Int

): Parcelable
```

Comment: if this doesn't work, also have to remember to remove following from gradle (inside android {} ) if previously using `kotlin-android-extensions`: 
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

Answer (score 3):

For me I had updated `firebase-crashlytics-gradle` from 2.5.2 to 2.7.1 in my **project** `build.gradle` and that caused the issue.

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1
}
```

I removed an unnecessary `firebaseCrashlytics` configuration in my **app module** `build.grade` and then it worked again:

```
// TODO this entire block had to be deleted to fix the issue
firebaseCrashlytics {
    mappingFileUploadEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem is common in Flutter 2.8

1. Delete Folder with all sub Folder of `C:\Users\LENOVO\.gradle`
2. Go **File** menu > **Setting** `(Ctrl+Alt+S)`
   Go **Appearance & Behaviour > System Setting > Android SDK > SDK Tool Tab**
   and then uncheck **Android SDK Build-Tool** press **OK** Button
   3)Run Project `(Shift+F10)` in Andriod Studio it will Download all required files from the internet and your issue resolve

   [image]

After if the issue is Not resolved then Second Step is:

4. Go > `android\app\build.gradle` in your project
   Please **Add** > **`minSdkVersion 19 or 20`**
   // `Remove it` because, 16 is by default minSdkVersion in flutter 2.8
   //`minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion`
5. add **multiDexEnabled true** if file size increase from limits

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remove `namespace` from the android block and put the package name back into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="you.package.here">

</manifest>
```

Comment: I commented the namespace statement under android block and saved my problem. thanks
//    namespace 'rocks.poopjournal.flashy'

Comment: in my code there is no namespace . and i appear this problem

Answer (score 2):

I added debug under buildTypes in the gradle file and missed a comma after "API_URL":

not working:

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL" "\"http://myapi.com/\""
    }
}
```

working:

```
buildTypes {
    ...
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "\"http://myapi.com/\""
    }
}
```

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was in this block

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "abc"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 12.1 **-> 13**
        versionName "3"
    }
```

The 'versionCode' mustn't be a decimal number

Comment: Além de Decimal, estava usando String numérica. Você e o cara!

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem similar to @LalitFauzdar 's but with a different solution. A plugin that I'm using requires custom ProGuard rules for release builds, but adding a reference to the rules file in the app gradle file resulted in the error in question. Here is the offending line, commented-out:

```dart
buildTypes {
  release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    // proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this line was the culprit for my case too. Also, the console error logs are HORRIBLE. Seriously, google couldn't have come up with worse logs.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error when i added 2 product flavors to my build.gradle app module file with the following names:

```
productFlavors {
    normal-sv1 {
    ...
    }
    normal-sv2 {
    ...
    }
}
```

Found out that this error was because of the '-' int the middle of the flavors' names.
When i used '_' instead of '-', like below, the error was gone.

```
productFlavors {
    normal_sv1 {
    ...
    }
    normal_sv2 {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I received this error while creating a new **Jetpack Compose** project. 'app' module's build.gradle was cracking up.

Removing **packagingOptions** did the trick for me ->

```
packagingOptions {
        
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no general answer to this problem. There is just something wrong with the `app/build.gradle`.

In my case I defined a variable named `versionCode` which caused the error. Renaming it to e.g. `versionCode_` fixed the problem.

Comment: Same issue for me. Looks like `versionName` and `versionCode` are reserved keywords.

Answer (score 2):

you only need to remove the below line from your build.gradle file in the app level

```
useProguard = true
```

Comment: If we remove this part the progourd did not work

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, so I tried to comment element inside `android{}` one by one

After commenting

```
    //    appVersion '3.1.3'
    //    outputFileName 'wmc' 
    //    enableCrashlytics()
    //    ignoreNonProductionReleaseVariants()
```

it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the kotlin android plugin instead of the kotlin jvm plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' // NOT kotlin-jvm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to comment this in your app level `build.gradle` file

```
openOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue because I had added a trailing comma `,` in defaultConfig in android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I had mispelled `signingConfig` as `signingConfigs`

So it is actually `signingConfig signingConfigs.{yourVariantName}`

And NOT `signingConfigs signingConfigs.{yourVariantName}`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. It is a nasty one.

I followed the answer first here [Deprecated Gradle features not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863724/deprecated-gradle-features-not-compatible) and ran in the terminal

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease
```

the gradlew command gave more detialed feedback, and turned out my Java and JDK were 32bit instead of 64 and also outdated...

This resulted in further errors, but could resolve them step by step:
[Invalid initial heap size -Xms4096M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421211/invalid-initial-heap-size-xms4096m)
[Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151 contains a valid JDK installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47291056/could-not-find-tools-jar-please-check-that-c-program-files-java-jre1-8-0-151-c)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning to just comment things and test, for me it was:

```
kapt {
    useBuildCache = true
}
```

Removed it, everything was building again.
Happened after updating Kotlin version.

Answer (score 0):

Old issue but worth noting you might need to follow the migration guide here if you see this issue:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

For me, removing the line `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` and adding view binding as below resolved the issue:

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after adding

```
kapt {
    // etc
}
```

because I hadn't added:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was misspelling the native libs command for gradle, as of version updates and old tutorials.

```
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'Android.mk'
        }
    }

... 
// But i had:  
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndk {
            path 'Android.mk'
        }
    }
```

But as the number of answer indicate, there are several possibilites for this issue.
Most probably after some version updates some gradle functions are no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the error after adding Flutter flavors. Apparently if you have flavor names which contain `-` it won't work.

e.g. Transformed names from `test-preprod` to `test_preprod` and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `useIR true` inside `kotlinOptions`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time its  missing dependencies, if you are using "dagger/Hilt"

- Ensure its added in project level  build.graddle

```
   dependencies {
       // ....
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    
    }
```

- add hilt plugin in the app level build.graddle

```
plugins {
 //....
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
```

- add complete hilt and dagger dependencies

```
   //hilt

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"

    // Dagger Core 
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.28"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28"

    // Dagger Android
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
    api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.31'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.31'

//Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.32-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that the Gradle Plugin update assistant replaced this:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "..."
}
```

With this:

```
androidResources {
        noCompress '...'
}
```

Undoing it, solved the build error. Of course this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line, it will work.

**includeCompileClasspath true**

Comment: This works for me. `includeCompileClasspath true` is deprecated in AGP 4.2 [see](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies?utm_source=android-studio#annotation_processor), maybe deleted in AGP 7.0.

Comment: This work for me too. I was using `javaCompileOptions { annotationProcessorOptions includeCompileClasspath false}}` after remove this code. It work.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got this error when I was making signed apk and I made a mistake while doing setup for playstore, In android/app/build.gradle

```
signingConfigs{
debug{
 .....
 .....
}
release {....}  // I added the release config outside the signing config
}
```

[Correct-way-todo-just-for-ref](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#adding-signing-config-to-your-apps-gradle-config)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a vanilla just-created new project in Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1):

The auto-generated build.gradle had this in it:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles
            getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Notice that `proguardFiles` "function call"'s parameters are on a separate line, this is not valid Groovy code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to remove following in `app/build.gradle`:

```
packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            pickFirsts += ['lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so', 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so', 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so', 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so']
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and tried out all the possibilities of the answers given. Most of the answers suggested to disable proguard. But I wanted to use Proguard. So by enabling Proguard i was able to fix this issue.

Following thing worked for me. I have been pointing

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
```

in android/build.gradle. Now to overcome this issue i pointed to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
```

Hope this helps for you as well !

Comment: I changed from 4.1.3 to 7.2.1 because that wasn't building.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @miguel, I solved the said issue by removing the namespace line from android block under Gradle. I am going to share a screenshot which may elaborate the solution clearly.
[image]`

//    namespace 'com.flashy.texting'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reduce `aab` file size and add some config to `build.gradle` file.

Remove these 2 lines will help

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true // <- this
            useProguard true // <- this
            .....
```

Answer (score 0):

useProguard true
command this line under app/build.gradle

//useProguard true

Answer (score 0):

Very simple!
This is specific to a project, not entirety of all projects.

**This worked for me:** Erase the entire thing in your `android/app/build.gradle`
But backup before you do! Please!!

Replace everything **with any** of your project **that-is-working's** `android/app/build.gradle`, and replace the **applicationId** with the **original.**

I hope this works your you too!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I **mistakenly wrote the below lines TWICE**.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I my case, I had to remove this from the app/build.gradle

useProguard true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

Answer (score -1):

In my case (old flutter project), the solution was to remove the "^" in pubspec.yaml for the lib causing troubles. The caret sign looks for any version from the specified version up to (but not including) the next non-breaking version is ok.

replace

```
pub: ^x.x.x
```

by

```
pub: x.x.x
```

It was making conflicts with a more recent version of the package

Answer (score -2):

In my case, the error cause is below

```
compilpepeeSdkVersion
```

rather than

```
compileSdkVersion
```