# Deprecated Gradle features not compatible

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-sdk-manager

I got this error when I run `react-native run-android`

Logs:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

Android Gradle Plugin Version - 3.6.3
Gradle Version- 6.0.1
```

Answer (score 10):

- Update the following files:

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
 distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
multiDexEnabled true   //add this
}
```

- Update all your third-party dependencies
- If the error still exists, run the below command:

  ```
  cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease
  ```
- Try this if it still exists:

  ```
  npm install --save-dev jetifier
  npx jetify
  npx react-native run-android
  ```