# Gradle doesn't sync after removing kotlin-android-extensions plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I try to remove below plugin from Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

But it doesn't sync and error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_43umlschc8aredhqs1z2ho67w.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_43umlschc8aredhqs1z2ho67w$_run_closure1) values: [build_43umlschc8aredhqs1z2ho67w$_run_closure1@786e3050]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Like which version of Kotlin you're currently using and have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi) link?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท actually i read it before but didn't help . i'm using version 4.1.1

Comment: Let's try with updating the Kotlin gradle plugin and the Kotlin version itself. Please try using the `1.4.21` version for the `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` and also set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'` in your project level module and then after syncing the project, do click on  `File - Invalidate caches / Restart` and see what happens next.

Answer (score 1):

1- just remove this code from android block in build.gradle:

```
android {
    androidExtensions {
       experimental = true
    }
}
```

or remove extra character like: semicolon or other extra character in android block in build.gradle

2- if you use parcelize in your project add:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

in your build.gradle.

then replace:

```
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
```

with :

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```