# How do you fix the following error : A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > No signature of method:

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, method-signature

I am getting the following error when trying to run my react-native app with android and I am unsure why, any ideas?

*Where:
Build file '/Users/ahmeeyagoldman/Documents/TikTok/android/app/build.gradle' line: 123

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_26i9j525hbm41pwpexiy08g68.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_26i9j525hbm41pwpexiy08g68$_run_closure1) values: [build_26i9j525hbm41pwpexiy08g68$_run_closure1@6ee8b6f5]
> My build.gradle file:

So far I have tried to:

- upgrade and downgrade my gradle,
  -clean and rebuild the project,
  -Invalidate caches/Restart,
  -Comment out new lines of code,
- Edit my configuration (didn't change much)

I can get an android application to run using react-native if I try another project but this one is throwing errors. Something to note I am not sure if it matters but this is connected to AWS.

```js
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tiktok"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' // <--- insert this line
        multidexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:1.0.3"


    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi

Comment: Thanks that article was definitely helpful. It took me down the path of commenting everything out until I found the error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error is found in the "multidexEnabled true" it should be "multiDexEnabled true" with a capital D in Dex.

If anyone ever runs into this same error again I would suggest that you begin to comment out every line of code that falls under android until you find the error.

The error is just referring to some syntax error in your code which may defer from someone else's program with the same error response.

Comment: i have issue when i add useProguard true but i dont know what error in this line

Comment: suggestion that you begin to comment out every line of code that falls under android  helped me solve the error.

Comment: I had this variable in a correct case but still had this problem

Comment: in my case, i removed  'useProguard true' and it works!!

Answer (score 2):

This might be old, but the solution is to comment out the useProguard on app\build.gradle

```
#useProguard true
#proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with [setting up Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/android-setup#4-optional-enable-crashlytics-ndk-reporting):

- they do not tell you (though it is probably obvious...) that you should also add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'` dependency (since you use the plugin)
- they tell you to add 'apply plugin' lines [at **the top** of your android/app/build.gradle file](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4314) which is easy to miss

---

In general: apparently, gradle cannot find (resolution of some) used function in the gradle build file - because of missing plugin / old gradle version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after changing versionCode to decimal value in app/build.gradle. The error was removed by changing the decimal number with positive integer(1,2,3...etc).

Answer (score -1):

This problem is common in Flutter 2.8

1. Delete Folder with all sub Folder of `C:\Users\LENOVO\.gradle`
2. Go **File** menu > **Setting** `(Ctrl+Alt+S)`
   Go **Appearance & Behaviour > System Setting > Android SDK > SDK Tool Tab**
   and then uncheck **Android SDK Build-Tool** press **OK** Button
   3)Run Project `(Shift+F10)` in Andriod Studio it will Download all required file from internet and your issue resolve

   [image]

After if issue is Not resolve then Second Step is:

4. Go > `android\app\build.gradle` in your project
   Please **Add** > **`minSdkVersion 19 or 20`**
   // `Remove it` because, 16 is by default minSdkVersion in flutter 2.8
   //`minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion`
5. add **multiDexEnabled true** if file size incress from limits

[image]

Comment: This did not help