# Could not find method android() for arguments [build_1c6nueis8xobld9$_run_closure2@7bfda345] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android

[Could not find method android() for arguments [build_1c6nueis5oxvjmg5bg8xobld9$_run_closure2@7bfda345] on root project 'android' of type org.gradle.api.Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsDdv.png)

Comment: You use java or kotlin ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally your grade file should containt the fowllowing line:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domaine.appName"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Try to include the missing line in between

```
android {
}
```

But don't forget to change **com.domaine.appName** by your domaine and appName.

[Please take a look here because it was already answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi)

Comment: Hi ther, thanks for your response. After adding all the lines i got this error

Comment: No signature of method: build_1c6nueis5oxvjmg5bg8xobld9.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1c6nueis5oxvjmg5bg8xobld9$_run_closure2) values: [build_1c6nueis5oxvjmg5bg8xobld9$_run_closure2@220c5c62]

Comment: ya i added it also i enable -minifyEnabled true, but i got the same error

Comment: So you are using kotlin or java language ? And then can you please show us the error log in PrintScreen.

Comment: project is on JAVA

Comment: hii you can go to he link, here i attached the screenshots

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DiVFVQvqNrXu4Sspn_ALNSYX1F7aihcH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So, @crazy4dev you get the solution ?

Comment: I updated my answer by adding a link, please take a look on it and after let me know if you have solve it or no.

Comment: Above, in my first answer. I Have marked it with the text "Please take a look here because it was already answered here."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi

Comment: ya i get it. After adding same as the code you sent me, I got the same error - No signature of method: build_1c6nueis5oxvjmg5bg8xobld9.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1c6nueis5oxvjmg5bg8xobld9$_run_closure2) values: [build_1c6nueis5oxvjmg5bg8xobld9$_run_closure2@7d89ba33]

Comment: Did you follow the solution on the link that I have shared ?

Comment: i read it already but i have the same error.