# How to fix the error arising while using flutter build appbundle: No signature of method?

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

I was getting the error while I was trying to build an app bundle of a flutter app in a release mode but while I run the command flutter build appbundle, this error just showed up.

```
 Building with sound null safety 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '<PROJECT_DIR>\android\app\build.gradle' line: 36

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_djjv0udzo4jemkigdf7i4cm25.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_djjv0udzo4jemkigdf7i4cm25$_run_closure2) values: [build_djjv0udzo4jemkigdf7i4cm25$_run_closure2@736f31fd]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.


BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                              4.5s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

And here is error part of android/app/build.gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion XX 
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release{
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']): null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes{
        release{
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

After trying a lot and following many articles I was not able to solve it.
here are some of the similar problems which I checked.

[problem_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi?page=2&tab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any right documentation to explain the issue but what I tried is commenting that only the **android block** and I found the issue only in these codes,

```
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

After commenting these lines I solved the issue of creating the app bundle of a flutter app.

Here is the output

```
flutter build appbundle                                                             
Running "flutter pub get" in app...                        Xms

 Building with sound null safety 

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from XKB to XKB: Removed X%
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             Xs
✓ Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab (X.XMB).
```

I think this would help someone : )