# reacct native preparing apk fails

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am in process of learning react-native, and in that regard, I initiated react-native default app, screenshots are attached.

I am struck at preparing apk via expo and react-native-cli both, when generating apk via exp it crashes on an android device whereas it works just fine in the browser, android, and ios simulators.

this is the error when exporting via react-native

I'm following this guidelines link https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

Any help or hint would be appreciated, thanks in advance

[image: app preview]
[image: ./gradlew --clean]
[image: ./gradlew build --stacktrace]
[image: npx react-native run-android --variant=release]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi

Comment: share build.gradle file

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danyal14/f7e8191b6d8578643a4a8796f64b00c9

Comment: @HardikDesai 
 gist.github.com/danyal14/f7e8191b6d8578643a4a8796f64b00c9