# How to fix Error - No signature of method: build_6dqn5epllms0i73v68pqhkim1.android() is applicable for argument types:

Tags: android

No signature of method: build_6dqn5epllms0i73v68pqhkim1.android() is applicable for argument types:

Comment: Here is my code

Comment: I don't see any code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using kotlin-android-extensions??

If yes ..Remove

```
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

[StackOverflow Question on similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi)