How to resolve 'No signature of method' error in Android Studio with Flutter and Firebase?
I am developing an Android application using Flutter and Firebase in Android Studio. During the build process, I encounter a 'No signature of method' error that I've been unable to resolve despite several attempts, including deleting specific lines and upgrading the Android SDK.
The error occurs specifically when trying to build the project, and here is the exact message I receive in the terminal:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\\Users\\rodri\\AndroidStudioProjects\\firebase_app\\android\\app\\build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_cfrixyjg4kz0lcy8fplw80i25.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_cfrixyjg4kz0lcy8fplw80i25$_run_closure2) values: [build_cfrixyjg4kz0lcy8fplw80i25$_run_closure2@3d71da18]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

This is the build.gradle section where the error points to, specifically around the configuration definitions:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.getx.app.db.firebaseApp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        MultiDexEnable true
    }
}

I have tried troubleshooting tips suggested by Android Studio and various online resources, but none have resolved the issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

some ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi
