# Flutter build.gradle Error " Build failed with an exception."

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, intellij-idea, build

I tried to build my Flutter app(bundle).
but i has some problem.

this is my error code:

```
-Error message
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\relayWriting\android\app\build.gradle' line: 42

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_c3l4fjlvmd1tu5wmv81djoazh.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_c3l4fjlvmd1tu5wmv81djoazh$_run_closure2)
values: [build_c3l4fjlvmd1tu5wmv81djoazh$_run_closure2@7e4ad7b4]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
```

I think I have some problems with my 'android\build.gradle'&'app\build.gradle'.
at android\build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

I think some problems with this ':app'->cause my builder has problem with evaluating project ':app'.

and 'app\build.gradle':

```
android {
```

this line has problem. but i don't know how to solve it.
I will write all code of this file at bottom of the article.

### I tried to...

1. delete all cash at Intellij & restart
2. add classpath at my 'android\build.gradle'

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
    }
```

3. add jcenter()&mavenCentral() at my 'android\build.gradle'
4. remove some code at app build file

```
useProguard true
```

& add some code.

```
shrinkResources true
```

5. move my key.jks file to '..\android'directory.

### I have some Qs

1. in `key.properties` file, I write my PW with ''.
   ex: `storePassword='myPWHere'`
   this form is right?
2. At Intellij, my `proguard-rules.pro` file looks like **has some ERRORS** [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgziA.png)
   I think this is just Intellij's mistake. It is true?
3. at Flutter project, android directory's moduel name has some form?

### Here is my code

this is `app\build.gradle`:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}


def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

//def flutterCompileSdkVersion = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.flutterCompileSdkVersion')
//if (flutterCompileSdkVersion == null) {
//    flutterCompileSdkVersion = '31'
//}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    ndkVersion "25.0.8775105"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.tastywaffle.relayWriting"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1.0
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
//            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
//            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
//        }
//    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

this is my `android\build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

& my gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

I really appreciate that your help.

Comment: im getting the same error as you. you managed to find a solution for this?

Comment: same, any solution? @HendryLim

Comment: Try with a newer version

Answer (score 3):

Try This

put **minSdkVersion** 20+

in android/build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

**OR**

in android/build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-bin.zip
```

Comment: My build.gradle still have same Error&Failure.
I change my minSdkVersion, classpath, distrivutionUrl

Comment: can edit your question and add some error info in it.

Comment: ok. I done. could u help me again?

Comment: visit maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi

Answer (score 0):

THis worked for me:
I just opened Task Manager
Click on **Details**
Right click on anything with **jave.exe**
Select **end task**
Rerun your application

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33677286)

Answer (score -1):

Change build gradle latest version.

In android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

If you have still the same error, try to remove properties from the release section in app/build.gradle, like `minifyEnabled`, `shrinkResources`.

```
buildTypes{
      release{
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            useProguard false
            debuggable false
```

hope so it will be helpful.